# Can you set up an update method in tkinter?

Tags: python, unity-game-engine, tkinter

I'm coming from unity and c# and learning python. Is there a way to create a method similar to the update or fixedupdate method from unity inside python using tkinter?

Comment: Do you mean an `update` method that redraws the `canvas` each frame?

Comment: yeah, something like that. I'm just experimenting with what is possible, so I'm making a stopwatch that I can then use to keep track of how much time I am actually focusing on learning. And I'm trying to pause it but getting errors that I figure are from python not running frame by frame like I'm used to. 
The error I'm getting is...
paused = not paused
    UnboundLocalError: local variable 'paused' referenced before assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tkinter` event loop is a different paradigm: most other GUIs like `pygame`, or `unity` redraw the entire canvas on the tick of a timer.

In `tkinter`, you define commands that the mainloop executes in due time.

something like this for a time counter, for instance:

```
import tkinter as tk

def tick():
    var.set(var.get() + 1)
    root.after(1000, tick)   # the tick function is called every 1000 ms 
                             # and updates the label

root = tk.Tk()

var = tk.IntVar(0)
label = tk.Label(root, textvariable=var)
label.pack()

tick()
root.mainloop()
```

This paradigm requires a different approach to reason about your app. It gives fine grain control over the widgets, and makes for a very powerful `Canvas` widget.